# Which site is the proper one for questions about PARI?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If I want help to program an algorithm in PARI ,

which site is the proper one ?

I asked several question about tetration and power towers, and still do not have
the desired algorithm managing all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is about the algorithm itself, ask it here (or TCS if it is "research level").

If it is about how to implement the algorithm in PARI, use StackOVerflow. They even have specific tags on [PARI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pari) for the C library and [PARI/GP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pari-gp) for the Computer Algebra System. (I am not sure which one you meant.)

Comment: I meant PARI/GP. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, here's [the MetaSO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175386/155839) about delineating the two tags.

Comment: $\exists$ http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @zyx: I didn't mention the CS site because I assumed that, given the choice of programming language, the OP's question, if is in fact about algorithms, would likely fall under number theory.

Comment: It's all good, but I just thought that where TCS site is mentioned, the CS one potentially relevant as well (and may not be as known in these parts).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to note that there is currently a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50072/mathematics-software-other-than-mathematica) for an SE site that would take exactly this kind of question. It needs more suggested questions, so posting your question there as well would help it on its way (it won't get an answer, though - so post it on SO too as suggested above.)

Comment: The proposal was deleted for inactivity.